# bluetoothd CPU usage constant at 100 %

Tags: pi-4, bluetooth, performance, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I've had this problem for a few months where the Pi 4 gets very hot to the touch, and it invariably turns out that `bluetoothd` is stuck at 100 % CPU usage, saturating one core. Currently `htop` tells me its `TIME+` is at `251h` (10.5 days) which seems to coincide pretty well with when the device was last turned on...

Normally it's not actually connected to any bluetooth devices, but when I turn e.g. a keyboard on it works fine. Just seems a bit excessive for bluetooth to draw ~1 watt of power all by itself for no benefit.

Is this a known problem, with a known solution? Or is my best bet to update to bullseye and just hope for the best?

Comment: I think if software were responsible for a problem this significant that has gone on for months, we would have heard about it, especially if it is on buster, so 1) You might as well try and update and hope for the best, 2) Otherwise there's not much to be done, it is broken hardware :(  Hopefully disabling bluetooth prevents it from happening.

Comment: @goldilocks Thanks for the input, I'll go with that strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to 64 bit bullseye seemed to work for a few weeks, but now the problem is back.

Since Bluetooth devices still work and the issue seems to appear more seldom I'll have to attribute it to a software defect with `bluetoothd`. After all I've never seen anything spit out more errors on any machine than the Linux Bluetooth stack ("host is down", "i/o error", "already in progress", ...)